# How to replace consecutive values in a list using another list as a reference?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a list like this:

```
list_target = [4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14]
list_primer = [3, 11]
```

So `list_target` consists of blocks of consecutive values, between which are jumps in values (like from `7` to `12`). `list_primer` consists of values at the beginning of those blocks. Elements in `list_primer` are generated in another process.

My question is: for each element of `list_primer`, how can I identify the block in `list_target` and replace their values with what I want? For example, if I choose to replace the values in the first block with `1` and the second with `0`, the outcome looks like:

```
list_target_result = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: How big are these lists? Is algorithm complexity an issue?

Comment: They are quite modest. `list_target` size is ~100 at most. `list_primer` is smaller.

Comment: Given your inputs, the contents of `list_target` is mostly irrelevant, since you just need it to get it's length

Comment: @GrandPhuba `list_target` is needed because I apply different values for different blocks. This simplified example uses only 2 blocks and 2 "primers" but the actual lists have more than that

Comment: Do the new values depend on the old values? If I'm getting you correctly you already have the `list_primer` generated, just a matter of updating `list_target`

Comment: you can use grouping to make this more clever

Comment: what would `[4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14]` look like as an output if `primer` stayed the same? or is it assured that there will be a `primer` value for each block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple algorithm which solves your task by looping through both lists beginning to end:

```py
list_target = [4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14]
list_primer = [3, 11]

block_values = [1, 0]

result = []

for i, primer in enumerate(list_primer):
    for j, target in enumerate(list_target):
        if target == primer+1:
            primer += 1
            result.append(block_values[i])
        else:
            continue
print(result)
```

```py
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Note that you *might* run into trouble if not all blocks have a respective primer, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying [method to find groups of strictly increasing numbers in a list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-find-groups-of-strictly-increasing-numbers-in-a-list/)

```
def group_seq(l, list_primer): 
    " Find groups which are strictly increasing or equals next list_primer value "
    temp_list = cycle(l)
    temp_primer = cycle(list_primer)

    next(temp_list) 
    groups = groupby(l, key = lambda j: (j + 1 == next(temp_list)) or (j == next(temp_primer))) 
    for k, v in groups: 
        if k: 
            yield tuple(v) + (next((next(groups)[1])), )
```

Use group_seq to find strictly increasing blocks in list_target

```
list_target = [4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14]
list_primer = [3, 11]
block_values = [1, 0]

result = []
for k, v in zip(block_values, group_seq(list_target, list_primer)):
    result.extend([k]*len(v))  # k is value from block_values
                               # v is a block of strictly increasing numbers
                               # ie. group_seq(list_target) creates sublists
                               # [(4, 5, 6, 7), (12, 13, 14)]

print(result)
Out: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works in `O(n)`, where `n=len(list_target)`. It assumes that your list_target list is consecutive in the way you described (increments by exactly one within block, increments of more than one between blocks).

It returns a dictionary with the beginning of each block as key (potential primers) and lower and upper indices of that block within list_target as values. Access to that dict is then `O(1)`.

```
list_target = [4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14]
list_primer = [3, 11]

block_dict = dict()
lower_idx = 0
upper_idx = 0 

for i, val in enumerate(list_target):  # runs in O(n)
  upper_idx = i + 1
  if i == len(list_target) - 1:  # for last block in list
    block_dict[list_target[lower_idx] - 1] = (lower_idx, upper_idx)
    break
  if list_target[i + 1] - list_target[i] != 1:  #if increment more than one, save current block to dict, reset lower index
    block_dict[list_target[lower_idx] - 1] = (lower_idx, upper_idx)
    lower_idx = i + 1
```

Here are the results:

```
print(block_dict)  # quick checks
>>>> {3: (0,4), 11: (4,7)}

for p in list_primer:  # printing the corresponding blocks.
    lower, upper = block_dict[p]  # dict access in O(1)
    print(list_target[lower:upper])
>>>> [4, 5, 6, 7]
     [12, 13, 14]

# getting the indices for first primer marked as in your original question:
list_target_result = [0] * len(list_target)
lower_ex, upper_ex = block_dict[3]
list_target_result[lower_ex: upper_ex] = [1]*(upper_ex-lower_ex)
print(list_target_result)
>>>> [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `numpy`.

```py
import numpy as np

list_target = np.array([4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14])
list_primer = np.array([3, 11])

values = [1, 0]

ix  = np.searchsorted(list_target, list_primer)
# [0,4]

blocks = np.split(list_target, ix)[1:]
# [array([4, 5, 6, 7]), array([12, 13, 14])]

res = np.concatenate([np.full(s.size, values[i]) for i,s in enumerate(blocks)])
# array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```